# C++ Making an Array with Custom Key and Value or something alike

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function that I set custom key and value to it and I would like to return them to a receiver so they can see, I want to be able to see the key and the value so I can do something with it, like in this example I print them.

The example I put down there it's pretty clear what I want.

```
//#functions.cpp

something returnKeyAndValue(){
     something valor;
     valor.login = "hey";
     valor.senha = "you";
     return valor;
}

something returnKeyAndValue2(){
     something valor;
     valor.value2 = "hello";
     valor.value1 = "string";
     return valor;
}

//... And a lot of other returnKeyAndValue functions

something PrintKeyAndValuesOfBoth(something KeyAndValue){

    for(int i = 0; i < KeyAndValue.size(); i++){
       string key = KeyAndValue[i].key;
       string value = KeyAndValue[i].value;

       cout << "Key: " << key << ", Val: " << value << endl;
    }

}

//#test.cpp

#import "functions.cpp"

int main () {

    something return = returnKeyAndValue();
    something return2 = returnKeyAndValue2();

     PrintKeyAndValuesOfBoth(return);
     PrintKeyAndValuesOfBoth(return2);

}
```

What could be this "something" type to do that something like it, how would I get the key and value of it.

I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

@Edit - Solution

Idea of using map provided by Dvir Volk, based on his suggestion I made this example to show how to use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main () {

    std::map< std::string, std::string > MyMap;
    std::map< std::string, std::string >::iterator MyIterMap; 

       MyMap["Teste1"] = "map1";
       MyMap["Teste2"] = "map2";
       MyMap["Teste3"] = "map3";
       
   MyIterMap = MyMap.begin(); 

   while(MyIterMap != MyMap.end() ) {
       std::string key = (*MyIterMap).first; 

       std::cout << "Key: " << key << ", Value: " << MyMap[key] <<std::endl;
       MyIterMap++;
   }
   std::cin.get();
   return 0;

}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Sometime, `something` is *something*, and sometime, it is *something else*. What exactly it is?

Comment: Yea, you know I am pretty clear in my example, so if it's not gonna be a constructive comment, don't do it at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need std::map or std::unordered_map.
You'll need to implement hashing or comparison function (for map) to use a custom key and not a primitive type.

You can of course create a vector of pairs, but then it will not be a key and value.

see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: I'll test it and I'll get back here if I get it, Thanks. :)

Comment: It's working as I expected, and I made an example of the solution, and added in the topic. :)

Comment: oh, that was easier than I thought. I thought the key itself should be a class. in this case you need to provide a comparison function comparing 2 objects of this class, for ordering your map. BTW if the order is not important, unordered_map is much faster for lookups, because behind the scenes it uses a hash table, whereas map uses a tree.

Comment: ohh good, The order doesn't matter, so according to the example I should use like this? std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > MyMap;
    std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string >::iterator MyIterMap;  in order to be faster, since the order is not important.

Comment: you might need to provide a hashing function, not sure, I haven't used this structure in a while.